# C# WebBrowser control page back to Windows.Form function

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a program that sends data from a windows application to a website. In the windows form, I am using the WebBrowser control to connect to the website and login. After I login I would like to be able to have a button that when the user clicks on it, it will call a function back in the windows.form so it can send the data to the website in the background. 
I can't figure out a way to do this, is this actually possible? Any help will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: how r u planning to send the data  and what kind of data it is??if you just want to upload files that u can directly do ... or if this data is something else than cant your website just ask for the data ?

Comment: Is the button on the winform or on the webform and -like @gsagrawal said - what kind of data are you talking about? (this is a reason to use services)

Comment: You can login and post data to website from windows application. How to do ? There are plenty of examples on internet that cover this.

Comment: Why do you need this to be a Windows Forms application? as @riffnl mentions a service would likely be better for this.

Comment: That button can't be the problem.  Just drop one from the toolbox and double click it to write the Click event.  Hacking the DOM with WebBrowser.Document surely is the real problem?  Nobody can help you with that if you don't describe what the DOM looks like.

Comment: I have some legacy software that is connected to the windows application. Through the application the user authenticates to a remote server via the webbrowser. Once successfully authenticated, the user needs to press a bottom from the remote website (webbrowser) and the windows application will send data from one local database to a remote database. The send data process is easy and I know how to do that. The problem is to instantiate the button so the windows application knows about it.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the "[button] from the remote website"?  Meaning do you have any control over the website portion? Are there any restrictions on it such as it must be HTML only no Javascript or ASPX?

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism that immediately comes to mind is a shared file.  Your WinForms application would setup a `FileSystemWatcher` on a shared directory.  Then the ASPX page would update the file so that your WinForm would know to upload the data.

I do not recommend this method, believing that a WindowsService that was notified via the ASPX page would be preferable, however the above should be a workaround if your are unduly constrained to the architecture you described.

Comment: Thank you to all for your comments. My windows form uploads data from other legacy software installed only on a local computer. It is imperative at the moment for me to use a windows application to connect to it. From the Windows form, I have a form with a webbrowser control in which I allow the user to sign in first. Once the user has authenticated, I have another screen where the user will have a button: e.g. CLICK HERE TO SYNC DATA. Once the user will click the bottom, I want to be able to send data from my local database to a remote database.

Comment: Because the sync data button is inside the webbrowser, I am trying to find out if I can send a signal to the windows form to start the send process. Thanks Joshua and the rest for your prompt response.

Comment: @carol1287 just because the database is local to the machine does not preclude your setting up a service.  Have a WCF service hosted in a windows service running locally on the box, then your aspx button click simply calls the WCF service and you transfer the data.