# Call a C# function from a button clicked on an HTML page

Tags: c#, html

My application (C#) consists of an embedded web browser which will load a page in HTML from a server. The HTML page will be created from scratch for this particular application. My intention is to have the following procedure:

- A user opens the application
- A web browser embedded within the application will load an HTML page
- User will click a button on the HTML page
- A C# function (on client side) is triggered from this action
- function does some work
- send a list of data back to the web page
- Web page will retrieve this data and display it
- user's browser will be refreshed to display the new page

Now my questions are the following:

- How can a C# function on the client side be triggered when a button is clicked on a server page
- What is the best way to transfer data (will probably be object)
- how can a function on the HTML page wait for data to be received before continuing to execute the function?

Comment: Why not just make the whole thing a web app and not an app that has a web browser? Makes the whole thing a lot easier...

Comment: See my answer to [C# Web browser back to WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025598/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-page-back-to-windows-form-function/10030138#10030138) but I agree with @RyanBennett this sounds like an AJAX web app to me.

Comment: Or alternatively it could be a WPF application if C# on the client side is really important. Either way, running a browser in a C# application and expecting it to execute other C# functions from the html content is like sitting on a bicycle in the driving seat of your car trying to make it turn the pedals of a second bicycle in order to get the car moving.

Comment: I know that there might be easier ways to go about it, but I have to work with this method for a particular project

Answer (score 0):

Using the WebBrowser control, you can use the [ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) property. This will allow JavaScript to call C# code using window.external.*C# MethodName*

There's some quirks with the serialization you might need to work through, and you might need to use *webbrowser*.Document.InvokeScript to trigger your data back to JavaScript (I've not personally used the result of a window.external call so cannot speak for it).